# How to retrieve field name in case of unmarshalling error in CXF?

Tags: cxf, field, unmarshalling, fault

**Precondition**: service based on CXF receives request/response with data, which violates XSD restriction.

**Actual behavior**:
In this case CXF returns fault with message like:

> cvc-maxLength-valid: Value 'string_length_violated_value' with length = '28' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '13' for type 'XSDStringTypeWithLengthRestriction'

**Goal**:
return fault to consumer with name of field which contains invalid data. F.e. something like this:

> Response from provider contains invalid data. Value 'string_length_violated_value' of field 'field_name' is not facet-valid with respect to maxLength '13'.

I'm wondering if it is possible and if so, then how to determine (where to retrieve from) this field name?

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem, where I get a "not valid value" Unmarshalling Error but without any hint about the element in question, except for the "offending value". Since I have hundreds of elements in the XML message, it's like searching a needle in a haystack. My workaround for this stage is to provide unique (bogus) values for each element and since values (but not elements) are reported, it points me to the right element. It's tedious and not very smart, though. I will try the `JAXB ValidationEventHandler` technique once I have a little more time.

Comment: Hi Daniel, much time passed so I don't remember detailed, sorry. But what I can say -- for me  `ValidationEventHandler` not worked, as version of cxf we used ignored this.
This is bad news, but there is good also -- I've managed to get data about "coordinate" (line and column number) from cxf fault by digging in encapsulated objects -- this was our solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will completely work, but you can give it a try:

You can create a JAXB ValidationEventHandler and register that on your endpoint.

The ValidationEvent that it gets has the basic string (that you see above)  and other information.  I would put a breakpoint in there and dig into the event to see if ANY additional and useful information is available.

Comment: great thanks I'll try it and inform if it'll bring any result!

Comment: Unfortunately, [this source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227684/1864054) states that [ValidationEventHandler](https://jaxb.java.net/jaxb20-ed/api/javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler.html) won't let you change responding behavior and you can't change SOAP response format. Is that true?